# How to change the highlighted text in an Eclipse dialog box's text entry box

Tags: eclipse

This question is **not** about changing the foreground/background on occurrences, so please don't reply with that as the answer.  I've already tried that even though I know it would not work.  This is not a text editor color setting either, since this is a dialog box text entry field.

I am currently running Eclipse 4.11 (2019-03)

Here is an example.  I open the Eclipse preferences dialog and there is a text entry box in the upper left with ghost text "type filter text".  I enter some text, then select a word.  When the dialog has focus, the highlighted text is unreadable because the foreground and background text are close to each other in brightness.

[image: Example of highlighted text in the Eclipse preferences dialog search box]

I am trying to discover how to change the foreground and/or background color of that highlighted text.

This is on MacOS and this is the Accent/Highlight color settings from System Preferences:
[image]

Comment: Linux or macOS?

Comment: On recent versions of macOS this is the 'Accent' colour configured in the General tab of the macOS system preferences.

Comment: This is MacOS.  The accent color that is currently set is dark yellow and the highlight color is a darkish grey.  Neither match that beige/white combo that my snapshot illustrate.